# Use Wicket as a REST API

Tags: java, http, rest, angularjs, wicket

I need Wicket to respond to a post request from AngularJS.

I set up a page in wicket like this but the request parameters are always empty

```
@MountPath(value = "/api/my/rest/url")
public class MyPostHandler extends SecureWebPage {

    public MyPostHandler () {
        final WebRequest webRequest = (WebRequest) getRequest();
        final HttpServletRequest rawRequest = (HttpServletRequest) webRequest.getContainerRequest();

        if (rawRequest.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("POST")) {
            webRequest.getRequestParameters().getParameterNames(); //Returns an empty list
            webRequest.getPostParameters().getParameterNames(); //Returns an empty list
        }
    }
}
```

The AngularJS code that is sending the POST request looks like this:

```
$http.post('/api/my/rest/url', {some:"data", other:"stuff"});
```

Any idea what's going wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: Not sure about Wicket, maybe you are sending json data from client, where as the server expect a form encoded data.

Comment: That sounds like it could be the case. Not sure how to tell wicket to read JSON data though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best solution but the following code is working for me

```
@MountPath(value = "/api/my/rest/url")
public class MyPostHandler extends SecureWebPage {

    public MyPostHandler () {
        final WebRequest webRequest = (WebRequest) getRequest();
        final HttpServletRequest rawRequest = (HttpServletRequest) webRequest.getContainerRequest();

        if (rawRequest.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("POST")) {

            BufferedReader br;
            try {
                br = rawRequest.getReader();
                String jsonString = br.readLine();
                //Do something with the JSON here
            }
            catch (IOException e) {

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Another potential solution I came across was this project https://github.com/bitstorm/Wicket-rest-annotations

Answer (score 1):

[WicketStuff REST Annotations](https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/tree/master/jdk-1.7-parent/wicketstuff-restannotations-parent) can help accomplishing this with built-in support for JSON serialization/deserialization.

Comment: Project `Wicket REST` moved to [this URL](https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/tree/master/wicketstuff-restannotations-parent)

Answer (score 1):

I used [Wicket rest annotaions](https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/tree/master/wicketstuff-restannotations-parent) in one of my projects. Here is [its the Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wicketstuff/wicketstuff-restannotations). Please find below an example:

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wicketstuff</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicketstuff-restannotations</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wicketstuff</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicketstuff-restannotations-json</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Create your Wicket REST resource:

```
import org.wicketstuff.rest.annotations.MethodMapping;
import org.wicketstuff.rest.annotations.parameters.RequestBody;
import org.wicketstuff.rest.resource.gson.GsonRestResource;
import org.wicketstuff.rest.utils.http.HttpMethod;

public class MyPostHandler extends GsonRestResource {    
    @MethodMapping(value = "/my/rest/url", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
    public boolean handlePost(@RequestBody SomeObject someObject) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And in your Wicket WebApplication init() method, register the rest resource:

```
    mountResource("/api", new ResourceReference("restReference") {
        MyPostHandler resource = new MyPostHandler();

        @Override
        public IResource getResource() {
            return resource;
        }
    });
```

Once the REST web service is up running, you can issue HTTP POST request:

```
POST URL: http://localhost:8080/api/my/rest/url
POST data: {json data for SomeObject}
Content-Type: application/json
```

That's it.